# Vue js 3 Passing dynamic model value inside a v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

I'm working on a product page which has a gallery and this gallery needs to change when different options is selected.

to simplify, imagine this is the gallery:

```html
<swiper-slide v-for="image in product.option" :key="image.id">
```

and I've radio buttons like this:

```html
<RadioGroup v-model="optionChoice">
```

I need to somehow pass optionChoice to v-for so it dynamically change when user selects an option. something like this:

```html
<swiper-slide v-for="image in product.{{optionChoice}}" :key="image.id">
```

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) is used to reference an object property by a dynamic key:

```js
const product = { name: 'john', age: 100 }

let optionChoice = 'name'
console.log(product[optionChoice]) // => 'john'

optionChoice = 'age'
console.log(product[optionChoice]) // => 100
```

The `v-for` value is a JavaScript expression, so the same solution applies:

```html
<swiper-slide v-for="image in product[optionChoice]" :key="image.id">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-dynamic-object-key?file=src/components/Slides.vue)